# float text on second image to the left

Tags: html, css

I have three images with text over them. I want to have text for first and third images to be floated to the left, and the second one to be floated to the right. I got the first and the third images to work, but I am struggling with the second image. I have been looking around but couldn't find any help. and also, I am new to html & css, so I would appreciate if someone could help.

```
<style>
.image { 
   position: relative; 
   width: 100%; 
}

h2{ 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 200px; 
   left: 0; 
   width: 100%; 
}

.h2:nth-of-type(2){
   position: absolute; 
   bottom: 200px; 
   left: 200px; 
   width: 100%;
}

h2 span { 
   color: white; 
   font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; 
   letter-spacing: -1px;  
   background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
   padding: 10px; 
}



.overlay-image {
 position: relative;

}

.overlay-image .image {
 display: block;

}

.overlay-image .text {
 color: #81282A;
 font-size: 30px;
 line-height: 1.5em;
 text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;
 text-align: center;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 width: 100%;
}




.overlay-image .hover {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: .5s ease;
}

.overlay-image:hover .hover {
 opacity: 1;
}


.overlay-image .normal {
 transition: .5s ease;
}
.overlay-image:hover .normal {
 opacity: 0;
}
.overlay-image .hover {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

.pp{
color: white;
}

#store-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
#store-image {
  opacity: 0.3;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transition: .5s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
#store-middle {
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
#store-text {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}

.TEXT{
position: relative;
width: 831px;
height: 134px;
left: 180px;
top: 56px;
padding-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 15%;

font-style: normal;
font-weight: 300;
font-size: 35px;
line-height: 47px;
text-align: center;
color: black;
}
</style>
<div class="image"><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0254/5067/6317/files/smart_large.jpg?v=1562170226" width="1179" height="480" alt="Alt text" />
<h2><span>Custom Smart Kitchens<br />We build Custom smart kitchens</span></h2>
</div>
<div class="pp">here</div>
<div class="image"><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0254/5067/6317/files/laptopRepair_large.jpg?v=1561171348" width="1179" height="480" alt="Alt text" />

<h2><span>We have our own designer</span></h2>

</div>
<div class="pp">here</div>
<div class="image"><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0254/5067/6317/files/electric_car_large.jpeg?v=1562179941" width="1179" height="480" alt="Alt text" />
<h2><span>We come and build it for you</span></h2>
</div>
<div class="pp">here</div>
<div class="TEXT">
<p>For more designs, visit us at the store.<br />      Call us to schedule a free quote</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to mark the h2 you want to align right diretly in the markup

So change the markup (html) of the second `<h2>` and add a class `<h2 class="right">` and apply the following additional css rules

```
div.image {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
}

h2.right {
  right: 0px;
  left: auto;
  width: auto;
}
```